# Simulating Physical Keypress

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

So I have a keyboard, and it has a mode where it lights up every key you press.
I was wondering if you could physically simulate a keypress, AHK just sends it directly to the system.
However I need a way to make the keyboard light up, because AHK doesn't do that. The keyboard is not programmable.

Solutions in mostly any language are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you want to send a simulate keypress to your fysical keyboard. (this is i think a mechanical switch insite the keyboard self, that does do light up if you press a key) and it is only possible if the company did make a keyboard driver that allows you to change the settings (disable - light up) in the Windows Registry. (you did not give me the name of your keyboard but you can then try to searching into the registry for example software/Logitech/settings)